B2C Identity Experience Framework doesn't generate the token in the last stage
I'm working on an Azure AD B2C custom policy to validate an email through a RESTful endpoint. If the validation and email verification are successful, I want to generate a token. I'm currently at the last step to generate the token, but I get the following URL: https://jwt.ms/?code=eyJraWQiOiI2WllIUmttREwyXzBvREF6UHhQWHZ. without any token in there. I am using it's went to the last step.
My requirements:
Use only email for validation and token generation. (no password just email validate and verification code)
Validate the email through a RESTful endpoint.
Generate the token if the validation and verification are successful.
Here are my questions:

What am I missing? The process reaches the last step, but the token is not generated. What did I do wrong?
Between steps 5 and 7, I'm repeating the same process to give the user three attempts to validate the email. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Relying Party
<TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuerWithEmail">
    <DisplayName>JWT Issuer With Email</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="None" />
    <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="client_id">{service:te}</Item>
        <Item Key="SendTokenResponseBodyWithJsonNumbers">true</Item>
        <Item Key="issuer_refresh_token_user_identity_claim_type">email</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
        <Key Id="issuer_refresh_token_key" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenEncryptionKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
    </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>


User Journey
<UserJourney Id="SignInAndSignUpWithEmailVerification">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- Register application insight -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="TrackSignInRequest" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AzureInsights-SignInRequest" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Show email registration page -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedEmailRegistration" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-EmailRegistration-Custom" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Check if the email is valid -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="REST-CheckEmailValidity" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-CheckEmailValidity" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Second try -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>isEmailValid</Value>
                    <Value>true</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedEmailInvalidRetry2" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-EmailRegistration-Custom-Retry" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Third try -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>isEmailValid</Value>
                    <Value>true</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedEmailInvalidRetry3" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-EmailRegistration-Custom-Retry" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- After third try it fails -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>isEmailValid</Value>
                    <Value>true</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedEmailInvalidFailed" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-EmailRegistration-Custom-Failed" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Transform email to readOnlyEmail -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="TransformEmailToReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="TransformEmailToReadOnlyEmail" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Show custom email verification page -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="UserProfile_EmailVerification_Custom" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerification-Custom-UI" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Generate the token -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuerWithEmail" />
    </OrchestrationSteps>
    <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>




Why have you changed JwtIssuer?
What happens if you use the definition in the starter pack?
If you want claims in the JWT, add them in the Relying Party.

I used this starter pack below but it is for password. I do not have object Id so I thought that could be the reason of JWTIssuer so I changed it but it is still not working
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/signin-email-verification/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions_EmailMFA.xml

To get an objectID you need to do a read

yeah as I explained, I don't need to read or write so I don't need objectId but email only
